# How to compose SPML v2 'modify' request to delete object attribute

Tags: soap, active-directory, spml, dsml

I need to maintain an Active Directory service via SPMLv2 SOAP requests to an [Active Roles Server](https://www.oneidentity.com/products/active-roles/).

I'm trying to do something ostensibly simple: delete the telephoneNumber attribute from an object. I'd never heard of SPML before so I spent some time trying to understand the specification available on the list of [OASIS open standards](https://www.oasis-open.org/standards).

I've figured out how to do it if the value is *known*. For example, the payload below will delete the telephoneNumber attribute if it matches the value '12345', but not any other value.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:urn="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <urn:modifyRequest xmlns:spml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0">
        <urn:psoID ID="CN=Some User,OU=User,OU=Accounts,DC=someorganisation,DC=org"/>
            <urn:modification>
                <modification name="telephoneNumber" operation="delete" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
                    <value>12345</value>
                </modification>
            </urn:modification>
        </urn:modifyRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I can't figure out is how to do this for an unspecified value, i.e. I don't care what the value is before I delete it, I just want to delete it. I suspect this has something to do with the SelectionType and I just need to use a 'match anything' selector, but I'm having trouble understanding the specification.

Any ideas?

Edit: To add to the confusion, I see we're using the DSMLv2 namespace for the modification. I just pulled this from a sample on the Active Roles SPML service documentation so I don't know how/why it works. The SPML specification does mention DSML but doesn't give any context around its usage as far as I can tell. It could actually be a vendor specific implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution/work-around to this problem.

To delete the attribute without knowing its current value, you can simply include a 'replace' operation to first set some arbitrary value and include it in the same modify request as the 'delete' operation.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:urn="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <urn:modifyRequest xmlns:spml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0">
        <urn:psoID ID="CN=Some User,OU=User,OU=Accounts,DC=someorganisation,DC=org"/>
            <urn:modification>
                <modification name="telephoneNumber" operation="replace" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
                    <value>deleteMe</value>
                </modification>
                <modification name="telephoneNumber" operation="delete" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
                    <value>deleteMe</value>
                </modification>
            </urn:modification>
        </urn:modifyRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```